# iOS 7 NavigationBar Back Button Custom Image with no Label

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, back-button, ios7-statusbar

I am trying to create a custom back button on a navigation bar. I start from the following:

```
// Nav bar - back button
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:COLOR_WHITE];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navMenuBackButton"]
                                                     imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6.0, -6.0, 6.0, -6.0)]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navMenuBackButton"]];
```

The image is 34x34 points so does not centre properly without the image alignment. The current problem is trying to get rid of the "Back" label without setting a blank title for each screen or making any changes on the ViewController itself.

Any idea's? Thank you

Comment: Thinking out loud really: How about subclassing UINavigationBar then using `UINavigationController - (instancetype)initWithNavigationBarClass:(Class)navigationBarClass toolbarClass:(Class)toolbarClass`

Answer (score 1):

Disable leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem. Try the following.

```
[navigationItem.backItem.leftBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
[navigationItem.backItem.rightBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
[navigationItem.backItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

```
NSString *backString = @"";
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:backString 
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                                              target:nil 
                                                              action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

Comment: Yes. It works the same as
`self.navigationItem.title = @"";`
But this needs to be called for each View Controller which I want to try and avoid